# Relay starts trigger about 6 times when connecting arduino to laptop

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

[image]I have a fairly simple code to turn a relay on-off every 2 seconds
When i attach the USB of the arduino Uno to the laptop, it goes into a frenzy and the relay triggers on off for 6 times within 3-4 seconds and then it settles down.
This however doesnt happen when connecting directly to the power output.

Is there something that needs to be wired to stop this happening ?

I am using an arduino Uno with a relay JQC-3FF-S-Z connected directly to the arduino pins.

```
const int ONOFF_TRIGGER_PIN = 2;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(ONOFF_TRIGGER_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(ONOFF_TRIGGER_PIN, LOW);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(ONOFF_TRIGGER_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: The code is so simple, this has to be a hardware problem. Please add a schematic or  a wiring diagram to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Jrobert ive added a fritzing image. Couldnt find the the exact same relay component i have JQC-3FF-S-Z

Comment: Put a voltmeter on the pin and to ground while the Uno is starting up with the relay detached. Note any fluctuations. Now, connect the relay with the voltmeter still attached, and restart the Uno. Do you see any difference with the voltage behaviour of the pin?

Comment: Are you sure your relay works on 3V supply? JQC-3FF-S-Z operates on 5VDC.

Comment: @stevieb - i dont have a voltmeter :(

So this issue only happens when connecting it to the computer. Not when its connected to just a power supply. Means that i have to connect pin 2 after the arduino has "booted"

Comment: @hcheung - Ive tried it on both 5v and 3v. it works on both.

Comment: The thing is that if you see your relay flicking on and off, it suggesting that you are not having enough power or current supply. So if it is 5V, uses 5V. The 3V on Arduino Uno is weak and not support to be used for supplying a relay....

Comment: @hcheung but after the first 3-4 seconds (which i assume is the arduino booting up or something), it starts to work as per the program, So its just the initial phase.
Also, when hooking the arduno to a powersupply, the relay pins are still connected to the arduino. So maybe the arduino i have is corrupted somehow

Comment: Well, this is all "poking in the fog" as we say over here. Without measuring the supply voltage, you can't be sure. -- If you can't afford a multimeter (a simple one will do), you might try to use an LED and a series resistor and give it just enough current to be dimmed. You might be able to see fluctuations.

Answer (score 2):

The markings on your relay suggest the coil is for 5VDC. But you have the coil supply wired to 3V3. Move the coil supply to 5V, and try again.

Comment: I agree with @Seamus. We don't know what might be going on with the 3v supply during boot up, but going to be marginal for a 5v even at steady state. At least try this and find out.